# How to send an automatic email via java webservice

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, email, sapui5

I have some data in a sapui5 application which should be sent to a receiver with a click on a button. 
With javascript, I can only use outlook for example to do that.

Is there a possibillity for a java based webservice, which I can invoke via javascript and send my information and attachements to, so that the webservice fetches this data end sends an e-mail to a receiver?

Comment: Any application server can be configured to send emails. Use a REST call or servlet to send your email. Or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: My problem is that I know how to send the email in java but I dont know how to make my java project as a webservice so that I can access the methods inside by my sapui5 application with javascript and pass my data to it so that it sends an email with the transmitted informations.

Comment: You can either expose it as a REST service using Jackson/Jersey for example, or use a simple servlet and send your mail in the doPost method